# I'm not able to insert record into oracle database using scala

Tags: java, oracle, scala

I'm trying to insert records into Oracle database using Scala and getting error

db1.scala:18: error: value commit is not a member of java.sql.Statement
                statement.commit()

```
object ScalaJdbcConnectSelect {

         def main(args: Array[String]) {
                val driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                val url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cdtsdcpt-scan.rxcorp.com:1521/DDCPAD00.WORLD"
                val username = "DCA_DATA"
                val password = "DCA_DATA"

                var connection:Connection = null

            try {
                Class.forName(driver)
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

                // create the statement, and run the select query
                val statement = connection.createStatement()
//                      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT org_short_nm FROM dc_org")
                val sql_st="INSERT INTO DCP_ITALY_STG" + " VALUES ('20411384','71771622','4378038','257.550','15.000')"
                statement.executeUpdate(sql_st)
                println("Inserted records into the table...")
                val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT num FROM DCP_ITALY_STG")
                connection.commit()
                println("Hello india")
                while ( resultSet.next() )
                {
                        val host = resultSet.getString("num")
                        println(host)
                        println("Hello india")
                }
            } catch {
              case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace
            }
                connection.close()

        }
        }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
connection.commit()
```

instead of

```
statement.commit()
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) says:

> `Connection#commit()` - Makes all changes made since the previous commit/rollback permanent
>   and releases any database locks currently held by this Connection
>   object.

Comment: Thanks@GurV now i'm getting this error     Reason: companion contains its own main method, which means no static forwarder can be generated.
 object ScalaJdbcConnectSelect {

Comment: @akhilesh can you post the code you're running as a EDIT in the question?